# Use character input to define function in R

Tags: r, function, character, distribution

I have an input data set, which may look something like this:

```
DF=data.frame(
    Variable = c("Test1", "Test2", "Test3"), 
    Distribution = c("Normal", "Exponential","Poisson"),
    Variable = c(2, 3, 4), 
    SD = c(2, NA, NA))
```

I want to use the random probability functions (e.g. `rnorm` `rexp` and `rbinom`) using the distributions given in the data frame `DF`.

So, how do I turn the text input into the correct functions?

I want to use the corresponding values in the `Variable` and `SD` columns as the mean values/standard deviations if appropriate.

Comment: Those functions have different input arguments that your `DF` doesn't have (eg., `size`, `n`). How do you think dealing with that?

Comment: It was just an example - the only missing parameter is `n` which for arguments sake say will be 10 for all distributions. The `Variable` column will be the mean for the Normal distribution, rate for Exponential, and lambda for Poisson. Should have everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@r.user.05apr solution is working, but involves some expression parsing which is not needed here. We might get this a lot easier by creating a list of functions to use them later.

```
# generating data:
DF=data.frame(
  Variable = c("Test1", "Test2", "Test3"), 
  Distribution = c("Normal", "Exponential","Poisson"),
  VariablePrm = c(2, 3, 4), 
  SD = c(2, NA, NA),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# creating function list and selecting this functions by Distribution column
fun_vec <- c(Normal=rnorm, Exponential=rexp, Poisson=rpois)
DF$fun <- fun_vec[DF$Distribution]

# if SD is NA then simply call function only with variablePrm
# else call with sd
# 10 is the number of observations to generate
generate <- function(x) {
  if(is.na(x$SD)){
    x$fun(10, x$VariablePrm)
  }else{
    x$fun(10, x$VariablePrm, x$SD)
  }
}
# if we apply this functions to each row we will get matrix of results
# each column will have 10 rows of generated data for previously selected distribution
apply(DF, 1, generate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
DF=data.frame(
  Variable = c("Test1", "Test2", "Test3"), 
  Distribution = c("Normal", "Exponential","Poisson"),
  VariablePrm = c(2, 3, 4), 
  SD = c(2, NA, NA),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# functions-lookup
fun_vec <- c("rnorm", "rexp", "rpois")
names(fun_vec) <- c("Normal", "Exponential", "Poisson")
DF$fun <- fun_vec[DF$Distribution]

# create expr
my_expr <- function(x) {
  txt <- paste0(x[1], "<-", x[5], "(", 10, ", ", x[3], 
                ifelse(is.na(x[4]), "", 
                       paste0(", ", x[4])), ")")
}
want <- apply(DF, 1, function(x) eval(parse(text = my_expr(x))))
colnames(want) <- DF$Variable
want
```